# Python bug - or my stupidity - EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, string, syntax-error, eol

I cannot see a significant difference between the two following lines.

Yet the first parses, and the latter, does not.

```
In [5]: n=""" \\"Axis of Awesome\\" """

In [6]: n="""\\"Axis of Awesome\\""""
  File "<ipython-input-6-d691e511a27b>", line 1
    n="""\\"Axis of Awesome\\""""
                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Is this a Python bug/feature/oddity, or have I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Just use `'''` instead of `"""`

Comment: `\\` won't escape the quotes, because it's an escaped backslash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last four quote marks in

```
"""\\"Axis of Awesome\\""""
```

are parsed as `"""`, i.e. end of string, followed by `"`, i.e. start of a new string literal. This new literal is never completed, though. Simple example:

```
>>> """foo""""bar"
'foobar'
>>> """foo""" "bar"
'foobar'
```

If you want to avoid this problem, then replace `"""` with `r'` or escape the `"`:

```
>>> """\\"Axis of Awesome\\\""""
'\\"Axis of Awesome\\"'
>>> r'\"Axis of Awesome\"'
'\\"Axis of Awesome\\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last 4 quotation marks are being evaluated as `"" & ""` instead of what you're expecting it to be evaluated as `" & """`.

Comment: Actually, it's parsed as `"""`, then `"`.