# how is the string """\\"Axis of Awesome\\\"""" interrupted in python

Tags: python, string

i read some info on python's EOL error, and i find [an explanation about that error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328385/1889327). The author gives an instance about the correct ones, however i can not figure out how does the string `"""\\"Axis of Awesome\\\""""` can work. Can someone do me a favor to explain how does the string interrupt.Thanks.

==================================================

the answer:
i thought it a lot and finally figure it out. The [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11328385/1889327) does the **`__repr__`** function on string and outputs **`\\"Axis of Awesome\\"`**, however in Hyperboreus's explanation, the **`__str__`** function on string has been called and eventually the result is **`\"Axis of Awesome\"`**. Actually, they are the same.

Comment: The backslash escapes the quote.

Answer (score 3):

```
"""\\"Axis of Awesome\\\""""
```

is parsed as

```
"""   \\   "   Axis of Awesome  \\  \"  """
1     2    3   4                5   6   7
```

1. Start of string literal
2. Escaped literal backslash
3. Literal quotation mark
4. Literal text
5. Escaped literal backslash
6. Escaped literal quotation mark
7. End of string literal

If you were to print this out, you'd get:

```
\"Axis of Awesome\"
```

The example you linked to has one fewer backslash at the end, and is instead parsed like this:

```
"""   \\   "   Axis of Awesome  \\  """  "
1     2    3   4                5   6    7
```

1. Start of string literal
2. Escaped literal backslash
3. Literal quotation mark
4. Literal text
5. Escaped literal backslash
6. End of string literal
7. Start of new singly-quoted string literal; since there's no close quote before the end-of-line, this is a syntax error

Comment: does the """\''' string allow backslash escape? and if it does, why the former **\\"** has not been escaped.

Comment: @Hyperboreus i am afraid not. i test it in my python 3.3.2, and it turns out that **`""""\\"Axis of Awesome\\\""""`** was interpreted as **`\\"Axis of Awesome\\"`** not **`\"Axis of Awesome\\"`**

Comment: @andy Then you seem to use some personal python3 which has its own standards. `print(""""\\"Axis of Awesome\\\"""")` outputs `"\"Axis of Awesome\"` as expected.

Comment: @andy Maybe you are a bit confused between the representation of a string and its content. Just a guess.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, i thought it a lot and finally figure it out. The **[explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328335/python-bug-or-my-stupidity-eol-while-scanning-string-literal/11328385#11328385)** does the **__repr__** function on string and outputs **`\\"Axis of Awesome\\"`**, however in your instance, the **__str__** function on string has been called and eventually the result is **`\"Axis of Awesome\"`**. Actually, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are confused with a three quotes ( """ ). This is a multiline quote. So, """\"Axis of Awesome\\""" is actually \"Axis of Awesome\\".

```
s = """ my name is
        abc
        and I am not a programmer ..."""
```

So, your actual string is in between the """. If you want to store this string, you have to do this:

```
>>> a = ' \\"Axis of Awesome\\" '
>>> a
' \\"Axis of Awesome\\" '
>>>
```